# How to place several elements in one row when using a list?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I need to create a content block which has to contain three events on each row.

I'm using Angularjs along with Bootstrap, so I designed my code as a list that starts from the main container of events **class="events"**

```
<ul class="events">

  <li class="event" ng-repeat="event in events">
    <ng-include src="'/assets/angular/events/particular_event.html'" class="ng-scope">
    </ng-include>
  </li>

  <li class="event" ng-repeat="event in events">
  ...
  <li>

  <li class="event" ng-repeat="event in events">
  ...
  <li>

  <li class="event" ng-repeat="event in events">
  ...
  <li>

</ul>
```

The point is there can be loaded unlimited numbers of these events, hence my question is how to write css so the list can correctly display three events in one row?

Comment: use bootstrap `md-col-4` instead of list

Comment: @maioman If I use **col-md-4** instead, all the events will be placed in one column like [so](http://imgur.com/nPn80lt)

Comment: what @maioman said, using class="col-md-4" should do the trick, you need of course three of these

Comment: @klskl Can you please remake my code snippet and put it in the answer so I can see it?

Comment: @maioman Thank you, you were right.

Comment: glad to help you out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't remake your code since I don't know what your 'events' are, but I did it like this:

in html:

```
        <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="event in events">
                <p>{{event}}</p>
        </div>
```

In controller (this is ofc just something I did to have data):

```
$scope.events = ['event1','event2','event3','event4','event5','event6'];
```

This created what I think is the desired effect, three objects on each row, two rows in this case.

Let me know if I should elaborate, or anything

Comment: Thank you, klskl. That actually did the trick, 'cause I checked it on my main project and this was working.

Comment: I'm glad, I have no idea why that JsFiddle didn't work (I'm bad at those, must learn I guess)

Answer (score 1):

The css code would be like this:

```
 ul.events li.event{
   display:inline;
 }
```

The trick to show 3 per row, would be to put them inside a container div, which has a resolution wide enough for 3.
If your block is say 180px wide then you need a 3 * 180px +margins/paddings box.